# Custom OpenDialogBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, openfiledialog

I am new to WPF and C# framework. I have a requirement where the user has to choose a .txt file and in addition to that, he/she has to have the capability to choose two more options(TextBox and Radio button). Is there a simple way that I can do this using OpenFileDialog?

```
private void Import_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //open a browser for .txt files
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

            dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
            dlg.Filter = "Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt";

            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();            

            if (result == true)
            {
                if (File.Exists(dlg.FileName))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Choose Options", "Choose different options before proceeding");
                    // Add Text box option here
                    // Add Radio button option here
                    }
                }            
        }
```

Comment: Please show your code so we can know what you've tried.

Comment: @Sippy: I have modified the question to include my code.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a modal window of type Window: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx 
And open it as a modal dialog with Window.OpenDialog: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx

In the Window created that way in xaml you'd need to add the button for opening the OpenFileDialog as you did above, and all the additional controls, that way you'd at least have it in one separated view. Unfortunately that's not as nicely customized and it doesn't use the WPF styles.

Here's a simple piece of xaml scaffolding which could be the wrapper for the OpenFileDialog button:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="Window1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Margin="4"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="..." MinWidth="40" MinHeight="40" Name="Button1"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Radio1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Another way would be to build the whole OpenFileDialog functionality - or at least the basics from the ground up the way I mentioned above just without the OpenFileDialog and with all the OpenFileDialog's controls handcrafted.